# Check whether back button is visible in action bar, or menu button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, back

How to check whether the left button in action bar is menu button or back button? To enable back button we use following:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I want to know which button is enable at a particular time. I tried by using stack count but it didn't worked for me.

Menu icon

[image]

Back icon

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Got any solution for this?

Comment: Any Solution on this @Harish @Vikrant?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

set ID:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
        menu.add((int groupId, int itemId, int order, charsequence title) .setIcon(drawable ID)
        return true; 
    }
```

get ID:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
    switch(item.getItemId()) 
    { 
    case  Menu.First+1  : 
        break; 
    case  Menu.First+2 : 
        break; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: NO.Here i want to know  whether the left button in action bar is menu button or back button.

Comment: How did you create your actionbar and set Items?

Comment: actionbar as follows  actionBar = getAppActionBar();  menu items using onCreateOptionsMenu .

Answer (score 0):

ok I have got the solution here is the Kotlin version

```
  val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
  val backButtonVisible = toolbar.navigationIcon != null
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using navigation drawer, then you can do this by knowing state of navigation drawer either open or closed.

Assuming you have defined a drawerlayout in XML:

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); 

if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
  //drawer is open
}
```

if your drawer is open it means you have back icon, else you have bar icon on action bar

Comment: it is either it is opened or not if i'm not wrong.I need to know whether it is menu or back.